# save information to SOAP using UWP

Tags: c#, windows, api, soap, uwp

I've been trying to google my way through but I end up scratching my head a bit on this question.

I'm a slow learner when it comes to code, but I don't really give up. As long as there is good documentation I can generally learn my way through.

My current question resolves around send data from an UWP app to a SOAP service. Fetching data is quite easy to find documentations about. But saving seems to be a whole different matter.

I've also tried to find it here through the last two days but not much is given.

Can anyone give me tips or an example code where we use C# to send data from an UWP app to a SOAP service?

The line of code in XAML which I want to send data on is quite simple.

```
<textbox>Int</textbox
<textbox>Decimal?</textbox
<textbox>String</textbox
<button name=send />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone give me tips or an example code where we use C# to send data from an UWP app to a SOAP service?

Firstly, you may see that how to call data from SOAP service, the common way is to use [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) class.

If you need to send data, also use this class, we need to construct Soap request from code behind, here is a simple demo:

The testing SOAP request like this:

```
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
        <s:Body>
            <Save xmlns=""http://TestService/"">
                <textbox>txt1</textbox>
                <textbox>txt2</textbox>
                <textbox>txt3</textbox>
            </Save>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

The Code sample:

```
 private async void btn_Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await AddNumbersAsync(new Uri("http://xxxxxx/TestService.asmx"), "txt1", "txt2", "txt3");
    }

    public async Task<int> AddNumbersAsync(Uri uri, string t1, string t2, string t3)
    {
        var soapString = this.ConstructSoapRequest(t1, t2, t3);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://TestServiceService/ITestServiceService/Save");

            var content = new HttpStringContent(soapString, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "text/xml");
            using (var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content))
            {
                var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return this.ParseSoapResponse(soapResponse);
            }
        }
    }

    private string ConstructSoapRequest(string t1, string t2, string t3)
    {
        return String.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
    <s:Body>
        <Save xmlns=""http://TestService/"">
            <textbox>{0}</textbox>
            <textbox>{1}</textbox>
            <textbox>{2}</textbox>
        </Save>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>", t1, t2, t3);
    }

    private int ParseSoapResponse(string response)
    {//Custom this function based on your SOAP response 
        var soap = XDocument.Parse(response);
        XNamespace ns = "http://TestService/";
        var result = soap.Descendants(ns + "SaveResponse").First().Element(ns + "SaveResult").Value;
        return Int32.Parse(result);
    }
```

Comment: Excellent answer, simple and clear.  Works perfectly. HttpContent content = new StringContent(sEnvelope, Encoding.UTF8, "application/soap+xml") works too.